# How to write/post files to website server through ESP 8266

Tags: smart-home, networking, esp8266, streaming

I want to know if there is a way to send files to a website with sm ESP 8266 or any other IoT device. I intend that the IoT device will be the client. A PHP or scripting file on the website will act as the server. It will look like the IoT device is uploading the files to the website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, files are uploaded using a [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) from a web form (I assume that's what you're thinking of when you say file upload). The exact format of the request tends to look a bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work), as defined in [RFC 1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867).

The ESP8266 [has an Arduino library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino), which contains a module called [`ESP8266HTTPClient`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient). There's a [basic example available here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpClient/BasicHttpClient.ino), to help get acquainted with the library, if you're interested.

The user 'gbafamily1' from the ESP8266 forums has [created an example](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=14235) that POSTs a 256 byte file, `data.bin` to `posttestserver.com`. It should be relatively easy to adapt this to your needs, and I'd expect to use something like this on the server-side HTML:

```html
<form action="posttestserver.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Upload File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="testfile" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you could implement the server side in PHP to accept the file being uploaded. There is a reference available [in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), and files sent by POST are stored in `$_FILES`.

With this example, the code above would allow browsers to upload, and the code provided by the ESP8266 forums would allow you to upload from the IoT device.

Comment: I am actually a newbie to php, can you help with a simple php code that will accept the file from the esp8266. Or if you have an example that can be adapted.

Comment: @Jojo The PHP documentation contains [a good reference and set of examples](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). You should be able to learn what you need from there. If you have any problems, they'd be best asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), since PHP isn't really an IoT topic in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this web server for IoT and realtime GPS tracking, https://iot.electronixforu.com
It supports Passthrough mode of ESP8266, it means you can send data as fast as you can (normally 1 second interval), details are available at https://electronixforu.com/iot.html